# What version of scrapy works with the scrapy wayback machine?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy to scrape text content off websites archived on the wayback machine using the middleware: scrapy_wayback-machine. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone used the scrapy_wayback-machine recently? Does anyone know what version of scrapy it is meant to be used with?

Are there other packages that work well with wayback machine?

I ran a very basic spider and got this warning:

```
2023-12-11 18:43:33 [py.warnings] WARNING: /Users/meganegler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy_wayback_machine/__init__.py:83: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: ExecutionEngine.schedule is deprecated, please use ExecutionEngine.crawl or ExecutionEngine.download instead
  self.crawler.engine.schedule(snapshot_request, spider)
```

So, I went into the init file and changed 'schedule' to 'crawl', and got this warning:

```
2023-12-11 18:54:52 [py.warnings] WARNING: /Users/meganegler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy_wayback_machine/__init__.py:83: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Passing a 'spider' argument to ExecutionEngine.crawl is deprecated
  self.crawler.engine.crawl(snapshot_request, spider)
```

This is kind of what led me to believe that there is a version incompatibility.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have to use a scrapy 1.X version, maybe try 1.8; although it could be outdated anyway due to changes at the Wayback Machine.

Comment: I flagged it since it's belong in the comment section.